# "Remount" a method in vue js component

Tags: javascript, laravel, websocket, vue.js, vuejs2

i'm not so well-versed in Vue.js or frontend so maybe what I'm trying to achieve is not the right approach, but here's my situation:

```
   mounted() {
        this.newMessages();
        this.scrollDown();
    },
    updated() {
        // prop gets updated from parent component, newMessages method depends on it
        this.$options.mounted = [
            this.newMessages(),
        ];
        this.scrollDown();
    },
    methods: {
        newMessages() {
            // logic, uses prop thread.id passed to component, needs to be initiated on mount
        },
        scrollDown() {
            // logic
        },
    },
```

**The question is:** How to I "remount" a method in Vue.js mounted hook component, if the updated hook fires?

Now, here's what happening, newMessages method get's a broadcast over websockets. It uses a prop called **thread** (**id** property of that object) to listen on specific channel.

Now when parent component changes that prop (thread) the DOM of the component changes to show messages from that thread, but that listener method still listens on a wrong channel.

I tried $options to reset mounted hook, but that only stacks the method mounted, and gets the same message multiple times.

Comment: Your case is a bit hard to understand, but it seems you are looking for either [computed properties or watchers](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html).

Comment: Well, watchers did help. In parent component I've set one that watches for that "thread" variable change, triggers a method that literally hides and then on nextTick() shows child component to "reset" it. Hacky but gets the job done, thanks :)